# Why ElasticSearch replica shards remain unallocated when replica comes back up?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I am running ElasticSearch 1.0.1 on Centos 6, with 32 GB of RAM.

There are 4 nodes, 1 with no data, and the rest with data.

There was a scenario where I manually shutdown one of the nodes (to restart it). When I restarted it, the replicas that were allocated to this node remain unallocated. I had to manually allocate them again using the allocate command.

My question is: How do I make sure the replicas get allocated automatically when it gets restarted? I don't want to do any manual allocation.

I have disable_allocation: false in my cluster settings so this shouldn't had affected it.

What else should I check?

Comment: in my case it was insufficient free disk space < 15%

Answer (score 0):

That shouldnt happen, I dont think.

Any chance your `allocation.disable_replica_allocation` is true?

In 1.0.1 these settings are deprecated but they still work:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
    "persistent" : {
        "cluster.routing.allocation.disable_allocation":false,
        "cluster.routing.allocation.disable_replica_allocation":false,
    }
}
```

What is the results of?

```
GET /_cluster/settings
```

**BTW - Looks like ES is deprecating:**

```
cluster.routing.allocation.disable_new_allocation
cluster.routing.allocation.disable_allocation
cluster.routing.allocation.disable_replica_allocation
```

In favor of:

```
cluster.routing.allocation.enable
```

Reference:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html